# Flutter websocket + spring. WebSocketChannelException: [object Event]

Tags: spring, flutter, dart, websocket

For the second day I can not make my flutter mobile application receive messages via websocket.

As I understand it, I use StompClien to work with Websocket message broker

There is only one error from the logs: WebSocketChannelException: [object Event]

I could not find information anywhere on the Internet either on this error or on how to work with web sockets on flutter.

I would be extremely grateful for any help!

Config from spring:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {


    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(final MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/ws");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(final StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/our-websocket").withSockJS(); 
    }
}
```

flutter app

```dart
StreamController<List<String>> streamController = StreamController();
String ws_url = "ws://localhost:8080/our-websocket/websocket";
String destination = "/topic/messages";
String message_destination = "/ws/message";
var _listMessage = <String>[];

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: MyApp(),
  ));
}

void onConnect(StompFrame frame) {
  stompClient.subscribe(
    destination: destination,
    callback: (frame) {
      Map<String, dynamic> result = json.decode(frame.body!);
      //receive Message from topic
      _listMessage.add(result['content']);

      //Observe list message
      streamController.sink.add(_listMessage);
    },
  );
}

final stompClient = StompClient(
  config: StompConfig(
    url: ws_url,
    onConnect: onConnect,
    onWebSocketError: (dynamic error) => print(error.toString()),
  ),
);

...(application rendering)
```

The spring web socket works if you use a web application as a frontend. js does exactly what I want it to do.

Answer (score 1):

at the method inside registerStompEndpoints, use

```
registry.addEndpoint("/our-websocket").setAllowedOrigins("*");
```

and also in the flutter ws_url variable, write "ws://localhost:8080/our-websocket"